# WP Query with multiple post types ordered by custom meta date then published date

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

Two post types blog and events. I want to list in the same query but order events by their event date and blogs by their published date:

```
                    $args = array(
                      'post_type' => array( 'post', 'event' ),
                      'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'event_start_date',
                            'compare' => '>'
                        )
                    ),
                    'orderby' => 'event_start_date post_date',
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                    );
                    query_posts($args);
```

The above doesn't display the blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will achieve this as stated. WordPress has no concept of post subsets in a query, it only understands it as single set as results.

If you don't need pagination you could just retrieve the set unsorted and re–sort it with PHP code. If you *do* need the pagination this would probably be extremely inconvenient and require massive custom SQL.

PS avoid `query_posts()`, it's outdated and harmful.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you can try an `EXISTS` `OR` `NOT EXISTS` `meta_query`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'event' ),
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
        'post_date' => 'ASC'
    )
);
```